# Can we use default parameters in EOS smart contract?

Tags: transactions, action

I have a action in my contract :

```
// @abi action
void ContractClass::submittxn(string memo,string memo2,uint64_t a = 61)
{
    ...
}
```

I try to set a as default parameter but when I push the transaction, it shows the following error:

```
Error 3015014: Pack data exception
Error Details:
Missing 'a' in variant object
```

I push the transaction as :

```
cleos push action contract_name submittxn'{"memo":"qwerty","memo2":"asdfgh"}' -p account_name
```

Is this possible in EOS or I have to find some other way?
It works fine if  I send this with full params.

Answer (score 1):

Not recommended, but you can mimic default value feature with `eosio::binary_extension`.

source:

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosio/binary_extension.hpp>

using namespace eosio;
using namespace std;

class [[eosio::contract]] test : public contract {
public:
   using contract::contract;

   [[eosio::action]]
   void submittxn(string memo, string memo2, binary_extension<uint64_t> a) {
       // if a is passed, _a has same value of a
       // if a is NOT passed, _a becomes 61 (default value)
      uint64_t _a = a.value_or(uint64_t(61));

      // use _a instead of a
      print(_a);
   }
};
```

result:

```
$ cleos push action test submittxn '["eosio", "token"]' -p test@active
>> 61

$ cleos push action test submittxn '["eosio", "token", 10]' -p test@active
>> 10
```

Comment: This is actually very interesting and creative. Thanks for sharing even though it isn't really a recommended practice.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use default parameters in actions. You could, however, check the value of the parameters and decide how to handle `null` or `empty strings`.

```
ACTION democontract::defaulttest( uint16_t i ) {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 61;
  }
  printf("i is %u", i);
}
```

Another option would be to declare a vector of types to send into the action and only use what is required.

**However you decide to proceed, you have to send in the same parameters that are declared in the ABI.** *A future version of EOSIO may add Variant actions, however they are not currently supported.*

Answer (score -1):

I guess, You use default and then save "a" with default to table database if it doesn't set.

If yes, You can use this way when declare table data

```
     struct account {
        string       memo;
        string       memo2;
        uint64_t     a = 61;
     };
```

Comment: Yes,This can be doable in table but why this is not supported in EOS ? may be possible I am not clear.